# Is there a way to get the PL/SQL maximum pls_integer?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way to determine the maximum possible value of a pls_integer either by a language predefined constant or a function? I can find the maximum on the internet (2^31 - 1 = 2,147,483,647), but I don't want to hard code it.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Why? Because it is not needed - `PLS_INTEGER's` maximal value is due to its maximal size - 4 bytes (and it is a signed datatype).

What is more, as stated in [documentation about PL/SQL datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#i10726), `PLS_INTEGER` is actually a `BINARY_INTEGER`. Look at the definition of `PLS_INTEGER` in the Oracle's `STANDARD` package:

```sql
subtype pls_integer is binary_integer;
```

And then take a look at the definition of `BINARY_INTEGER`:

```sql
subtype BINARY_INTEGER is INTEGER range '-2147483647'..2147483647;
```

Nowhere in the `STANDARD` package header can you find a constant which holds the maximal value of those datatypes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any constant that you can use; however, if it is so vital not to hard code any values, you can calculate the maximum value with the method given below.

This solution is based on the assumption that the maximum value would be in the form of 2^b-1 where b is the number of bits.

This is the function you can use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MAX_PLS_INTEGER_SIZE RETURN PLS_INTEGER AS 
  p PLS_INTEGER;
  b NUMBER;
BEGIN
  b := 0;
  WHILE TRUE LOOP
    BEGIN
      p := POWER(2, b)-1;

      b := b + 1;
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        EXIT;
    END; 
  END LOOP;

  RETURN p;
end;
```

After you create the function, you can test it:

```
SELECT MAX_PLS_INTEGER_SIZE FROM DUAL;
```

Result:

```
MAX_PLS_INTEGER_SIZE
--------------------
2147483647
```